# Left outer join and count does not list all the rows

Tags: mysql

```
$select = "select  f.root_id,f.dateTime,f.name,count(fs.id) as sub_count,CONCAT(u.name,\" \",u.surname) as creator_name_surname".
            " from forum as f ".
            " left outer join users as u on u.id=f.creator_id".
            " left outer join forum as fs on fs.record_root_id=f.root_id"
            ;
    $params = " where fs.status=1 and f.status = 1 and f.record_root_id=$root_id and f.kullanici_firma_id=$kullanici_firma_id";

    $group_by =" GROUP BY f.root_id,f.dateTime,f.name";
```

This query does not list the rows in f with `count(fs.id)=0`. But I need to list all other rows no matter count 0 or greater. What is my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that is with the WHERE filter `fs.status=1`. This is causing the LEFT JOIN on the `forum fs` table to act like an INNER JOIN. You should place that filter on the JOIN instead.:

```
select  f.root_id,
    f.dateTime,
    f.name,
    count(fs.id) as sub_count,
    CONCAT(u.name,\" \",u.surname) as creator_name_surname
from forum as f 
left outer join users as u 
    on u.id=f.creator_id
left outer join forum as fs 
    on fs.record_root_id=f.root_id
    and fs.status=1 
where f.status = 1 
    and f.record_root_id=$root_id 
    and f.kullanici_firma_id=$kullanici_firma_id
GROUP BY f.root_id,f.dateTime,f.name
```

Comment: bluefeet - Thanks really indeed. It has solved my problem. That s magic... Thanks..

Comment: @abkaplan1 Glad it's working, if this is helpful to you, then consider accepting it via the checkmark to the left of it.